# Javac doesn't recognize strings

Tags: java

```
import acm.program.*; 
import acm.util.*;

public class Order { 
public  int ocode;       
public String cname ;  
public String cphone ;  
public double price ; 
public double discount ; 
public int delay;
double finalprice  ;

public Order (int ocode, Item aItems, String cname, String cphone, String odate) {

     this.cname= cname;
     this.cphone= cphone;
     this.odate= odate;
     this.ocode = ocode; 
     price = aItems.getPrice() ; 
     if (aItems instanceof Peripherals){
          discount = price*0.25 ; 
     } 
     else if (aItems instanceof Hardware){
           discount = price * 0.3 ; 
     }  
     finalprice = price - discount ; 
     delay = rgen.nextInt(1,40) ;

  } 
  RandomGenerator rgen= RandomGenerator.getInstance() ;   

 public Item getItem() {
 return aItems;
 }

 public String getCname() {
  return cname;
}

public String  getCphone () {
return cphone;
}

public String getOdate () {
 return odate;
}


  public void print() {
         if(aItems instanceof Monitor){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered      Monitor: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " and your order will delay "  +delay + " days" );              
           }            
          if(aItems instanceof Mouse){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered Mouse: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay  );
           }
          if(aItems instanceof Printer){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered Printer: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay  );
           }
          if(aItems instanceof Keyboard){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered Keyboard: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay  );
           }
         if(aItems instanceof Proccesor){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered Processor: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay  );
           }

         if(aItems instanceof Motherboard){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered Motherboard: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay );
           }

         if(aItems instanceof Ram){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered Ram Memory: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay  );
           }
        if(aItems instanceof Gcard){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered Graphics card: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay  );
           }

         if(aItems instanceof HardDrive){

              println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Ordered HardDrive: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " " + delay  );
           }


    }
 }
```

And when i try to compile it it gives me these errors:

```
Order.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Monitor: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's nam
e: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + "
and your order will delay "  +delay + " days" );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
Order.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Mouse: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's name:
  " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + " "
+ delay  );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
Order.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Printer: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's nam
e: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + "
" + delay  );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
Order.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Keyboard: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's na
me: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate + "
" + delay  );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
Order.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Processor: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's n
ame: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate +
" " + delay  );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
Order.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Motherboard: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's
 name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate
+ " " + delay );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
Order.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Ram Memory: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's
name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate +
" " + delay  );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
Order.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red Graphics card: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer
's name: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odat
 e + " " + delay  );
                  ^
  symbol:   method println(String)
 location: class Order
 Order.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
                  println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" + " ,Orde
red HardDrive: " +   aItems   + " ,Final price: " + finalprice + " ,Customer's n
ame: " + cname + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone + " ,Date of order: " + odate +
" " + delay  );
                  ^
symbol:   method println(String)
location: class Order
9 errors
```

What is that?? Does not javac understand that these are Strings?? And if now, why??
Please help me compile this thing.The class Order is called by main class and it creates object of class order that represent orders made by an online shop.

Comment: `System.out.println` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try System.out.println() rather than println()

Comment: I am using acm package so command println should be correct. But i will try it

Comment: +1 It is complaining it cannot find the *symbol* which in this case is `println`

Answer (score 0):

In case of `acm` the method `println` is a part of `IOModel` interface. So, unless your class implements this interface, you can't use it - you just trying to call it from the class inherited from `Object`. Obviously, `Object` class itself has no such method. But if you put `Order` class inside some class inherited from `acm.program.Program` or `acm.program.ConsoleProgram`, for example, you will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this

```
System.out.println( "Order Number: " + "( " +  ocode + " )" 
                + " ,Ordered      " + aItems.getClass().getSimpleName() 
                + ": " +   aItems   
                + " ,Final price: " + finalprice 
                + " ,Customer's name: " + cname 
                + " ,Customers phone: " + cphone 
                + " ,Date of order: " + odate 
                + " and your order will delay "  +delay + " days" );
```

This saves having a println for every type of item.